# Special Pythagorean triplet whats the answer?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Special Pythagorean triplet Problem 9
    // There exists exactly one Pythagorean triplet for which a + b + c = 1000.
    // Find the product abc.
    // A Pythagorean triplet is a set of three natural numbers, a < b < c, for which
    int a = 1, b = a + 1, c = 0;

    while(true){
        ++a;
        ++b;
        c = 1000 - a - b;
        if(a * a + b * b == c * c && a < b && b < c)
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Value of a is " + a);
    System.out.println("Value of b is " + b);
    System.out.println("Value of c is " + c);
    System.out.println((a + b + c));
    System.out.println((a * a) + (b * b));
    System.out.println((c * c));

   }

}
```

The output is:

```
Value of a is -1852266809
Value of b is -1852266808
Value of c is -590432679
1000
a^2 + b^2 is -420041039170392640
c^2 is -249648399
```

Is this answer acceptable or no?

Comment: It won't be acceptable because sum of square of integers won't be negative in normal math. I guess you should use `java.math.BigInteger`.

Comment: You should move `a` and `b` independently.

Comment: @MikeCAT If `a + b + c = 1000` and `0 < a < b < c` then `c <= 1000` for sure, which means that `int` is fine. No need for `BigInteger`. You second comment is spot on, so maybe give that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not acceptable because square of real numbers will never be negative, so sum of them won't be negative, either. Overflow happened and that is the reason why you are getting the wrong result.

What you did wrong is that you are searching only for `b = a + 1`. You should check all combinations of integers `a` and `b` in `1 <= a < b < 1000` and `b < c`.

Comment: Hint: Answer is `a = 200, b = 375, c = 425`.

Comment: Now that I look at it you are right overflow is what happened. But I. The problem it never states that a > 0.

Comment: @NoobCoder You mean natural numbers should include 0?

Comment: Thanks for making me look like an idiot. Lol I'm going to stop talking. I'll take some of you guys advice and see if I can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys Solved it. All you need to do is make sure the number is natural xD and basically brute force it with a nested loop. Thanks to all who contributed.